# How to re-render after updating useState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What I want is that after I push the button, and the `useState` had refreshed, I want to refresh the content.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import MessComponents from './messConatiner';


function Conatiner() {
  const [messes, setMesses] = useState([
    {name: "Chater1: ", mess: "Hi", status: "left"},
    {name: "", mess: "Hi!", status: "right"},
    {name: "Chater2: ", mess: "I have some trouble with react...", status: "left"}
  ]);

  function Send(){
    let list = messes;
    list.push({name: "", mess: document.querySelector("input").value, status:             "right"});
    setMesses(list);
    console.log(messes);
    }

  return (
    <div className="container" id="cont">
        <MessComponents messes={messes}/>
        <input className="chat-input" type="text" /> 
        <button onClick={Send}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Conatiner;
```

Comment: React will automatically re-render when state is updated.

Comment: You are expecting `console.log(messes);` after `setMesses(list);` to log the updated `messes`. It will absolutely not as `setMesses` and `setState()`/`useState()` is asynchronous.

Comment: I console.log()-d and the state was updated, but the UI was not.

Comment: The problem here is that you're mutating the original list, which may interfere with change detection. `list = messes` is pointless, you need to make an actual copy.

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Use a method which returns a new array, push mutates. E.g. `newArr = array.concat(newItem)` or spread `newArr = [...array, newItem]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. whenever you call setMesses() this will automatically re-render. One thing to add is that the function Send should be lowercase, only capitalize components not regular functions.
2. the problem is that you are trying to directly mutate the array in your statement `list.push()`

try using this instead of push

```
let list = [...messes, {name: "", mess: document.querySelector("input").value, status:  "right"} ]
setMesses(list)
```

Comment: I chanced it, but still no update on the UI  :((

Comment: are you mapping over the array to display the UI?

Comment: The change you've suggested is unconnected to the first paragraph. Please rewrite this to be internally consistent.

Comment: Thank you! I initialized 2 times list. I fixd it, and it is working! Thank you!!! :))

Comment: please mark as answer if i helped solve your problem! you're welcome

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to keep the first paragraph because it actually corresponds to his question. I added an addition statement to try to explain what was wrong in his code. Is this better?

Comment: I marked it :))